# validate dateTime/dateTime value using xsd

Tags: xml, validation, datetime, xsd

I am trying to do xsd validation for the Google product feed and is struggling to validate the contents of `<g:sale_price_effective_date>2011-03-01T13:00-0800/2011-03-11T15:30-0800<g:sale_price_effective_date>`.

This need something like `<xs:element name="sale_price_effective_date" type="xs:dateTime" />`. since the value is a combination of start period and end period seperated by a '/', I cannot validate.

I tried the below

```
<xs:element name="sale_price_effective_date" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:simpleType name="sale_price_effective_date">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="-?([1-9][0-9]{3}|0[0-9]{3})(-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))?)" />
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>`
```

and also tried many regexpatterns from which was supposed to be matching one part, but it didn't.
Out of the two dateTime values, if we can validate one, I believe we can continue the same validation separated with the '/' should resolve the problem..

Kind of stuck with this.

Comment: Have you considered to use two separate element (xs:dateTime)?

Comment: The field "sale_price_effective_date" is somthing that i will not have control of. how can i use two elements for a single field.? It would be good if somehow can split the valu to two and do validation of the values for dateTime, seperately would be good.. but i do not know how to achieve this.

Comment: In order of increasing strictness:  (1) Just make it a string and trust Google not to send garbage; (2) Make it a simple regex that covers format without concern for all date constraints; (3a) Just make it a string and verify outside of XSD;  (3b) Use XSD 1.1 assertions.

Comment: Thanks for that..I am having problems in using assertions of xsd 1.1, in eclipse it straight away complains and when added the settings in processing java program, it still does not work.. One option is to transform that and convert to two tags and then validate..

Comment: I tried using `^(19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3})-((0(1|3|5|7|8)|10|12)-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])|(0(4|6|9)|11)-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)|(02)-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]))\x20(0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:[0-5][0-9]){2}$` in pattern but it complains about `\x20` and on removing that, it does not validate